Creating a udev rule to mount a drive
I got a drive attached to a Ubuntu 22.04 system which randomly disconnects sometimes (I guess a loose contact is the problem). Since I need this drive I wanted to find a way to automount the drive (like hotswap) every time it disconnects and then connects back after a few seconds.
For this I tried to create a udev rule which runs when a partition of the drive is detected and then mounts this partition. However I cannot get this to work and cannot figure out why.
The rule looks like this:
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd?1", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="4eac45cc-236a-43fd-89fe-6c8872749c3f", RUN+="/usr/bin/logger --tag Media-SSD-Mount Mounting the media SSD (%k)", RUN+="/usr/bin/mount /dev/%k /home/felix/server/Jellyfin/data/media"

The rule runs however I get a permission denied for mounting the drive. The log looks like this
  21002 Mar 31 13:44:23 grievous systemd-udevd[488540]: sdb1: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-media-ssd.rules:1 RUN '/usr/bin/logger --tag Media-SSD-Mount Mounting the media SSD (%k)'
  21003 Mar 31 13:44:23 grievous systemd-udevd[488540]: sdb1: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-media-ssd.rules:1 RUN '/usr/bin/mount /dev/%k /home/felix/server/Jellyfin/data/media'
  21004 Mar 31 13:44:23 grievous systemd-udevd[488540]: sdb1: Setting permissions /dev/sdb1, uid=0, gid=6, mode=0660

  21017 Mar 31 13:44:23 grievous systemd-udevd[488540]: sdb1: Running command "/usr/bin/logger --tag Media-SSD-Mount Mounting the media SSD (sdb1)"
  21018 Mar 31 13:44:23 grievous systemd-udevd[488540]: sdb1: Starting '/usr/bin/logger --tag Media-SSD-Mount Mounting the media SSD (sdb1)'
  21019 Mar 31 13:44:23 grievous systemd-udevd[488540]: Successfully forked off '(spawn)' as PID 488571.
  21020 Mar 31 13:44:23 grievous Media-SSD-Mount: Mounting the media SSD (sdb1)
  21021 Mar 31 13:44:23 grievous systemd-udevd[488540]: sdb1: Process '/usr/bin/logger --tag Media-SSD-Mount Mounting the media SSD (sdb1)' succeeded.

  21022 Mar 31 13:44:23 grievous systemd-udevd[488540]: sdb1: Running command "/usr/bin/mount /dev/sdb1 /home/felix/server/Jellyfin/data/media"
  21023 Mar 31 13:44:23 grievous systemd-udevd[488540]: sdb1: Starting '/usr/bin/mount /dev/sdb1 /home/felix/server/Jellyfin/data/media'
  21024 Mar 31 13:44:23 grievous systemd-udevd[488540]: Successfully forked off '(spawn)' as PID 488572.
  21025 Mar 31 13:44:23 grievous systemd-udevd[488540]: sdb1: '/usr/bin/mount /dev/sdb1 /home/felix/server/Jellyfin/data/media'(err) 'mount: /home/felix/server/Jellyfin/data/media: permission denied.'
  21026 Mar 31 13:44:23 grievous systemd-udevd[488540]: sdb1: Process '/usr/bin/mount /dev/sdb1 /home/felix/server/Jellyfin/data/media' failed with exit code 32.
  21027 Mar 31 13:44:23 grievous systemd-udevd[488540]: sdb1: Command "/usr/bin/mount /dev/sdb1 /home/felix/server/Jellyfin/data/media" returned 32 (error), ignoring.

The rule runs (as expected) as root (tested with whoami) so permissions should not be a problem.
I looked around and found this post which says mounting a drive with mount is not possible and systemd-mount should be used instead. However this is a post for arch linux and I don't know if this even applies to Ubuntu as I have found some examples which use mount (here and here).
So I tried to use systemd-mount and adjusted my rule to
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd?1", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="4eac45cc-236a-43fd-89fe-6c8872749c3f", RUN+="/usr/bin/logger --tag Media-SSD-Mount Mounting the media SSD (%k)", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemd-mount /dev/%k /home/felix/server/Jellyfin/data/media"

However this generates the following error
  26743 Mar 31 14:06:47 grievous systemd-udevd[495468]: sdb1: Running command "/usr/bin/systemd-mount /dev/sdb1 /home/felix/server/Jellyfin/data/media"
  26744 Mar 31 14:06:47 grievous systemd-udevd[495468]: sdb1: Starting '/usr/bin/systemd-mount /dev/sdb1 /home/felix/server/Jellyfin/data/media'
  26745 Mar 31 14:06:47 grievous systemd-udevd[495468]: Successfully forked off '(spawn)' as PID 495499.
  26746 Mar 31 14:06:47 grievous systemd[1]: Mounting /dev/sdb1...
  26747 Mar 31 14:06:47 grievous mount[495500]: mount: /dev/sdb1: /dev/sdd1 already mounted or mount point busy.
  26748 Mar 31 14:06:47 grievous systemd[1]: dev-sdb1.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
  26749 Mar 31 14:06:47 grievous systemd[1]: dev-sdb1.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
  26750 Mar 31 14:06:47 grievous systemd[1]: Failed to mount /dev/sdb1.
  26751 Mar 31 14:06:47 grievous systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /home/felix/server/Jellyfin/data/media.
  26752 Mar 31 14:06:47 grievous systemd[1]: home-felix-server-Jellyfin-data-media.mount: Job home-felix-server-Jellyfin-data-media.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
  26753 Mar 31 14:06:47 grievous systemd-udevd[495468]: sdb1: '/usr/bin/systemd-mount /dev/sdb1 /home/felix/server/Jellyfin/data/media'(err) 'A dependency job for home-felix-server-Jellyfin-data-media.mount failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.'
  26754 Mar 31 14:06:47 grievous systemd-udevd[495468]: sdb1: Process '/usr/bin/systemd-mount /dev/sdb1 /home/felix/server/Jellyfin/data/media' failed with exit code 1.
  26755 Mar 31 14:06:47 grievous systemd-udevd[495468]: sdb1: Command "/usr/bin/systemd-mount /dev/sdb1 /home/felix/server/Jellyfin/data/media" returned 1 (error), ignoring.

When I try to run this code in a normal shell I get the same error:
┌─[14:20:26]-[:)]-[rootgrievous]-[/home/felix/server/]
└──> /usr/bin/systemd-mount /dev/sdb1 /home/felix/server/Jellyfin/data/media
A dependency job for home-felix-server-Jellyfin-data-media.mount failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.



┌─[14:21:24]-[:)]-[felix@grievous]-[/tmp/]
└──> sudo journalctl -xe
░░ A start job for unit home-felix-server-Jellyfin-data-media.mount has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 6034 and the job result is dependency.
Mär 31 14:20:26 grievous systemd[1]: home-felix-server-Jellyfin-data-media.mount: Job home-felix-server-Jellyfin-data-media.mount/start failed with res>

Mär 31 14:21:16 grievous systemd[1]: Mounting /dev/sdb1...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit dev-sdb1.mount has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit dev-sdb1.mount has begun execution.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 6064.
Mär 31 14:21:16 grievous mount[499568]: mount: /dev/sdb1: /dev/sdd1 already mounted or mount point busy.
Mär 31 14:21:16 grievous systemd[1]: dev-sdb1.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ An n/a= process belonging to unit dev-sdb1.mount has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 32.
Mär 31 14:21:16 grievous systemd[1]: dev-sdb1.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ The unit dev-sdb1.mount has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Mär 31 14:21:16 grievous systemd[1]: Failed to mount /dev/sdb1.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit dev-sdb1.mount has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit dev-sdb1.mount has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 6064 and the job result is failed.
Mär 31 14:21:16 grievous systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /home/felix/server/Jellyfin/data/media.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit home-felix-server-Jellyfin-data-media.mount has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit home-felix-server-Jellyfin-data-media.mount has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 6055 and the job result is dependency.
Mär 31 14:21:16 grievous systemd[1]: home-felix-server-Jellyfin-data-media.mount: Job home-felix-server-Jellyfin-data-media.mount/start failed with res>
M

with the relevant part being
mount: /dev/sdb1: /dev/sdd1 already mounted or mount point busy.

So I guess there are two questions:

Can I use mount (instead of systemd-mount) and why do I get the permission denied error?
Why does systemd-mount try to mount the partition to another partition instead of the mountpoint I specified?
Bonus: Is udev even the right tool for this? Should I use another method? As I understood fstab is for mounting drives at startup and not while the system is running.

Thank you for your help!
